# Custom ViewController Transition

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I saw a tutorial on [Appcoda Transition](http://www.appcoda.com/slide-down-menu-swift/) `ViewControllers` `transition` a menu from up to bottom and I implemented it. Then, I tried to `transition` from bottom up using `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning`. But, doing it wrong cause I was setting the wrong values I think. Below is the code

```
func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    //Get reference to our fromView, toView and the container view
    let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)
    let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)

    //Setup the transform for sliding
    let container = transitionContext.containerView()
    let height = container?.frame.height
    let moveDown = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, height! - 150)
    let moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -50)

    //Add both views to the container view
    if isPresenting {
        toView?.transform = moveUp
        snapShot = fromView?.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
        container?.addSubview(toView!)
        container?.addSubview(snapShot!)
    }

    //Perform the animation
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9, initialSpringVelocity: 0.3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: 0), animations: {
        if self.isPresenting {
            self.snapShot?.transform = moveDown
            toView?.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        } else {
            self.snapShot?.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            fromView?.transform = moveUp
        }
        }, completion: {finished in

            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            if !self.isPresenting {
                self.snapShot?.removeFromSuperview()
            }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return duration
}

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    // Get reference to our fromView, toView and the container view
    let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
    let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

    // Set up the transform we'll use in the animation
    guard let container = transitionContext.containerView() else {
        return
    }

    let moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, container.frame.height + 50)
    let moveDown = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -250)


    // Add both views to the container view
    if isPresenting {
        toView.transform = moveUp
        snapshot = fromView.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
        container.addSubview(toView)
        container.addSubview(snapshot!)
    }

    // Perform the animation
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {

        if self.isPresenting {
            self.snapshot?.transform = moveDown
            toView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        } else {
            self.snapshot?.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            fromView.transform = moveUp
        }

        }, completion: { finished in

            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)

            if !self.isPresenting {
                self.snapshot?.removeFromSuperview()
            }
    })
}
```

This Should work. I checked out the tutorial you shared and you probably can't see the menu on the bottom because the way the MenuTableViewController.swift is set up on storyboard it is made so that the menu is always started from the top, so change that up and it should work perfectly fine. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is what I get http://www.imageno.com/m7fqtttwn8c7pic.html same experience I had. The view is supposed to push the First View UP, instead it's running underneath it

Comment: oh, both of them do that. They don't exactly push anything up or down. It just makes the view you are on slide a little down or up. You know what I mean? I can fix the file for you to make the menu appear at the bottom. you would just have to play with the MenuTableViewController in storyboard and make them appear at the bottom. You can do this by adding a view and making the list start at the bottom or something like that.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. That would do

Comment: If your question has been answered, please accept the answer. Thanks :)